# Django permalink not working for blog app

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls, permalinks

I am trying to get my blog posts to return a permalink so that I can ping them to blog directores, however when I call the permalink function I have created there is always an error. Everything I have found from googleing/stackoverflowing gets one error or another!

The most common error I am getting back is:

```
Reverse for 'viewpost' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': u'site-redesign'}' not found.
```

My model for this error:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    ...
    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('viewpost', (), { 'slug':self.slug})
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    ...
    (r'^post/(?P<page_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', 'viewpost'),
    ...
)
```

If i print: reverse('blogPost', kwargs={'slug': self.slug }) I get the correct url.

What am I doing wrong.

I am calling the function via:

```
signals.post_save.connect(
    ping_directories(content_attr = 'body', url_attr = 'get_absolute_url'), sender = BlogPost, weak = False)
```

If you need any more info please let me know.

--EDIT more views

```
#pages

(r'^post/(?P<page_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', 'viewpost'),

(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/page/(?P<page_number>[0-9]+)/$', 'viewcategories'),
(r'^category/$', 'listcategories'),

(r'^tag/(?P<tag_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/page/(?P<page_number>[0-9]+)/$', 'viewtag'),
(r'^tag/$', 'listtags'),

(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', 'viewcategories'),
(r'^tag/(?P<tag_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', 'viewtag'),
(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),

(r'^page/(?P<page_number>[0-9]+)/$', 'index'),
(r'^$', 'index'),
)
```

and the views:

```
def viewpost(request, page_slug):
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, post_status = 'published', slug=page_slug)
    path = settings.BLOG_PATH

    return render_to_response("blog/detail.html", { "post": blog_post, "path":path}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

You've called the kwargs page_slug in the url and slug in your permlink

Comment: Would i just do: return ('viewpost', ())

Comment: `return ('viewpost', (), { 'page_slug':self.slug})`

Comment: That comes back with: Reverse for 'viewpost' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'page_slug': u'site-redesign'}' not found.

Comment: Hope that helps. I am stumped! Cheers

Comment: Your views, not your urls.  What does the function signature of "viewpost" look like.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Thanks again :) python/django isn't my strong point!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the method calling my get_absolute_url also needed an extra callback so I was getting misled. Apologies for the confusion! Offending code:

```
signals.post_save.connect(ping_directories(content_attr = 'body', url_attr = 'get_absolute_url', feed_url_fun=lambda x: 'http://example.com/feed/address/here/'), sender = BlogPost, weak = False)
```